# Where is the "current working directory" located on my Windows machine (after running pwd )?

Tags: windows, configuration, environment-variables

When I run command `pwd`  in Putty , it says the current directory is :

```
/home/coffee
```

But where does this correspond to on my Windows-machine? I searched online and found that there's an environment variable called  `%USERPROFILE%` , but is that the correct one ?

Comment: Off-topic here, try Super User.  But the question could also be clearer; are you using Putty to connect to your Windows machine from a remote machine?  What protocol are you using?  If SSH, which third-party SSH server is installed?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I'm using Cygwin + JSch for my SSH

Comment: OK, so presumably JSch uses Cygwin's UNIX file system emulation, so you want to look at the Cygwin documentation.  Arguably that makes the question marginally on-topic here, since Cygwin is, I suppose, "used mainly by developers".  I don't know the answer offhand, but someone else might, and it's so basic that even if it isn't in the Cygwin FAQ it should be easy to find in the documentation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just write a file with a distinctive name to `/home/coffee` and then search for it in Windows.